# Dynamic attribute filters (on Amasty Improved Navigation)

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

We use to have a filter on our previous magento installation which shows the

- New Arrivals
- New on Sale products
- Back in Stock products

But our developer left the team and hasn't told us how he has coded that.

When I check the attributes from the admin panel, there are attributes called `prod_options`, `backinstockdate`, `pricechangedate`.

`prod_options` is filterable and it has New Arrivals, New on Sale, Back in Stock as option values. But the prod_options field is empty on all products. I thought this should be a dynamic attribute.

The template hints show
`Amasty_Shopby_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute` / `frontend/base/default/template/amasty/amshopby/attribute.phtml`
But this doesn't give me any clue! How can I find the code behind this filter?

Our new site works on Magento 1.9.2.4. We also use Amasty Improved Navigation extension.

Thx

Comment: It seems to me that the code you are looking for will be mostly located within you Amasty_Shopby extension

Comment: @Goku I checked the code frontend/base/default/template/amasty/amshopby/attribute.phtml. There is nothing related with this filter.

Comment: You will not find much logic inside a template file, if you are looking for rendering logic, then you should be looking at the block `Amasty_Shopby_Block_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute` instead